# PowerBI DAX Measure Performance extremely slow

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

Why does PowerBI performance get effected so badly when adding DAX measures to a model?

I have a model with a couple hundred DAX measures and a report that contains a couple of these measures on them.  This report runs fine as expected.  There is 2 reports that we look at here, one in PowerBI and another in Excel connected to the PowerBI model.

I modified the underlying model to add a whole bunch of additional DAX measures somewhere in the range of 2000.  Basically, I added different versions for Plan & Actuals for a number of rows in our P&L. Then created various comparisons i.e. vs LY, vs Plan, etc.

Now when I view the report in PowerBI it takes a bit longer to load and view the same report without any modifications to the report.  The biggest problem is when I look at the report in Excel, it now takes multiple minutes for the report to refresh.

My question is: Why is refresh affected so much by this change even though it is not used anywhere.  My understanding is that it wouldn't be affected by the additional measures that are not being used.

Comment: Pivot tables pull metadata to show. That takes time when you have very large models. But you should not see any difference on a published report in Power BI.

Comment: Have you tried using Performance Analyzer to try to catch reasons for decreased performance? You can also use DAX Studio (free tool) for the same purposes. https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/dax-studio/